# Thymeleaf Input validation

Tags: spring, forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot + Thymeleaf for building a web application and I added validation to my form inputs.
Is there a way to do the validation without classes and with only Thymeleaf syntax in the web page (just like javascript)?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Thymeleaf on its own, no.

Comment: Thymeleaf is not built for this no. You can use the 'pattern' html attribute to do some validation using regexes or add javascript if you need more.